# function returns only first array value with mysqli query result

Tags: php, arrays, function, mysqli, return

I have a small problem with my mysqli related function. Here is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
 if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     return $row;
  }
```

The problem is that when I use this function `$row` appears to be an array, but with only the first value from the query result in it. 
But if I try to `return var_dump($row)` instead, function displays array as expected, with all the values from the query result.
Can you please explain why is this happening and how to return an array with complete query result correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data  = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data[] = $row;
  }
}
return $data;
```

Comment: What makes your answer better? You are just returning an object

Comment: And what should be returned instead? It's weird, to say the least, serializing an array first only to deserialize it back immediately after.

Comment: after facing a need to get a larger amounts of data from DB this way seems to be the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 return $row;
}
```

For:

```
function test(){
 $query = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
 if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $data[]=$row;
  }
}else{
 $data=array();
}
 return $data;
}
```

Call test function

```
$bbb=test();

foreach($bbb as $key){
   $dbTableColumn1 = $key['column1'];
   $dbTableColumn2 = $key['column2'];
   $dbTableColumn3 = $key['column3'];
   //...$variable = $key['ColumnOfYourTable'];
   $text .= $dbTableColumn1.'|'.$dbTableColumn2.'|'.$dbTableColumn3.'<br/>';
  //Whatever you want to output
}
```

The function is only for make more readable

Comment: A function like this should not return formatted data. A nested array have to be returned instead

Comment: @YourCommonSense sorry man, but that is depend of what you want to print out, in the case you say return $row outside the while returned the array

Comment: Sure, it depends on what you want to print out. But the problem is - there can me Many different printing formats. And it's printing facility to decide, not data manipulation one. Please learn MVC.

Comment: then @YourCommonSense to understand better what you'r saying, you can give me an example(url) how to manipulate the data after get a nested array..to learn how to make the right way...thanks

Comment: I would use a *nested* foreach